# How to hide menu item of same page of side menu bar . in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-directives

In app.component.ts, I added all pages of the menu item, when Home page is open I want to hide Home menu item from side menu bar and same for all pages. I was trying to use class name by for hide but it affects to all menu items css. Please give me the solution:

```
 constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
      this.initializeApp();

      this.pages = [
                      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage, icon:'home' },
                      { title: 'Order History', component: OrderHistory, icon:'timer' },
                      { title: 'Profile', component: Profile, icon:'person' }
                    ];
     }

    openPage(page) {
                    console.log("open Menu");
                    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
                    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
                    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);   
    }
```